# How to add a propery to a dynamic object knowing the name of the column only at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic

[This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/09/30/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject/) shows how to add properties to a dynamic object.

```
dynamic contact = new ExpandoObject();
contact.Name = “Patrick Hines”;
contact.Phone = “206-555-0144”;
```

What if I've instead an array of columns `["Id", "Name", "Phone"]`.

```
DataTable dt = ContactRepository.GetContactInfo(sqlText, columns);
```

When I get the result, I'd like to do something like

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   dynamic contact = new ExpandoObject();

   foreach(string colName in columns)
   {
      // extract the value of the column from the row
      // add an property that has the same name has the column name
   }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid to have to check for each possible columns before adding it.

There are at least 36 columns.

```
if(columns.Contains("Phone"))
   contact.Phone = row["Phone"].ToString();
```

This last feature that I'd really like to implement to avoid all those checks.

Thank you for helping

Comment: `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, so you can cast it and work with it as with dictionary.

Comment: Implementing `IDictionary<string, object>` is very common like Dapper ORM has internal class DapperRow, which implements the same and result can be directly type-casted to contain Column name and cell data, which helps in achieving the flexible schema

Answer (score 4):

So, I don't know how to work with `DataRow` class, but I know how to work with `Expando` in this case:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    IDictionary<string,object> contact = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach(string colName in columns)
    {
        contact.Add(colName,row[colName]);
    }
    dynamic contactDynamic = contact as ExpandoObject;
    Console.WriteLine(contact.Phone);
}
```

**Be care! `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary` interface, not `Dictionary` class.**

Comment: So Contact object was converted to ExpandObject? Nice!

Comment: Will it work for `Hierarchical` structure, where a child object is of type `List<T>`

Comment: Also this still may not solve the issue related to knowing whether a column exist of not and then access it , as OP doesn't plan to check multiple columns using `if else` (whether they exist or not). Until and unless a standard structure with default values are used, they can then be accessed using Expando object. Non default / No null values will be actual object properties